# стилизация кнопки

Tags: css

у кнопки есть background
как сделать background opacity 0.2(к примеру)
в тоже время чтобы на color(цвет шрифта) оно не влияло

Comment: `background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2)` .

Answer (score 0):

это делается не через opacity.
правильно добавить цвет через rgba(0,0,0,0.7)
например

```
button{
background:rgba(0,0,0,0.7);}
```

будет прозрачно-черным